# How to add components in tina simulation schematic editor that are not available in TINA library?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, simulation, buck

I am using [TINA simulation software](http://www.ti.com/tool/tina-ti) free version for dc to dc buck converter design. I want to draw the below schematic myself in TINA platform for simulation purpose. But while using TINA editor ,I am facing difficulty i.e. I am unable add components like transformer with extra auxiliary winding ,[UCC28C40](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjc9MKA2JDQAhXFQo8KHS-QCG0QFggoMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fgpn%2Fucc38c43&usg=AFQjCNEHpB79cSp8W8StvfsEwfx7seMfKw) ,NMOSFET .These parts are not included in the TINA library .

[image]So how should I add these components in  the schematic?

Comment: IIRC... The free version of TINA from TI only allows you to use the libraries provided by TI, you cannot import other models or create your own. There is a paid for version of TINA that may remove these restrictions. For these reasons a lot of engineers use LTSpice. Its free. Its got a lot of models and libraries, and you can create your own models.

Comment: @SteveG but there are component like TI [UCC28C40](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjc9MKA2JDQAhXFQo8KHS-QCG0QFggoMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fgpn%2Fucc38c43&usg=AFQjCNEHpB79cSp8W8StvfsEwfx7seMfKw) and also one [phototransistor](http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/33524/VISHAY/TCMT1109.html) . Does LTSpice contains the above component?

Comment: TI has a PSpice model of the UCC28C40, you can use that in LT Spice. The other part is an opto-coupler, again LT Spice has models for those. Often you have to search the web for the models and libraries that you need.

Comment: @SteveG as per your suggestion I have downloaded the LTspice free version and using it for the first time.  Trying to draw the schematic hoping that I will find the required library files.